# RawCap sniffer results in empty pcap file

Tags: pcap, packet-capture

So... I'm attempting to use RawCap to capture traffic to localhost
When I run rawcap, it reports packets in the cmd prompt - but the dump file is always empty.

Any ideas (I've tried running with admin privs)

Comment: how are you running it? (Show command)  also might be better @ super user vs stack overflow

Answer (score 10):

You should terminate RawCap with ctrl+c and not by just closing the window.

for more information here:
http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-10&post=Automatic-Flushing-in-RawCap

Answer (score 2):

Set the `-f` flag to flush the data to the file after each package.

```
rawcap -f 127.0.0.1 my_loopback.pcap
```

Then as geniaz1 said, stop capture with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>